# Django admin - users username field shows my email instead of username

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I have a User modal with username and email fields. I use postgresql.

For every user in the admin panel my email is shown on the Username field on the production version of the app (AWS). Locally this is not the case. In the database the usernames are shown correct.

In admin.py I simply have:

`admin.site.register(User)`

Does anyone have an idea why this is the case on production and not local? And how to fix this.

**Solution:**

When I checked admin from an incognito tab everything works fine. It seems like Chrome sets my email address in the Username field for some reason.

Comment: Can you precise what django settings are different between local and production environments ?

Comment: @RomanMkrtchian On local only Debug=True and the Databases settings (except Engine). So almost identical.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've overridden the `USERNAME_FIELD` attribute in your `User` model. Changing this field to `USERNAME_FIELD = 'random_field'` will affect your string method in `User` class because in this method object shows whatever that is in the `USERNAME_FIELD`.

You can override your `__str__` method because in admin page the default return value of an object is the returned value of this method. So you can add this method to your model like following:

```
class User(SomeParentModel):
    ... some fields ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username # Or any other fields that you want
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right that I set USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'. But I just checked the admin of production again from ingocnito and everything works. I guess Chrome automatically sets my own email address in the Username field for some reason.